Regular Surfaces and Jacobian
I'm trying to do this exercise and I saw that the cross product has something to do with the determinant of the Jacobian, but I don't really get what the Jacobian is or how they're connected. Can someone help me out with this and show me how to solve the problem, please?
Definition 1. A subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface if, for each $p \in S$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a map $\boldsymbol{x}: U \rightarrow V \cap S$ from an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $V \cap S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$\boldsymbol{x}$ is differentiable. This means that if we write
$$\boldsymbol{x}(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)), \quad (u,v) \in U,$$
the functions $x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)$ have continuous partial derivatives of all orders in $U$.

$\boldsymbol{x}$ is a homeomorphism.

(regularity condition) For all $a \in U$, the differential $d\boldsymbol{x}_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is injective.


Exercise. Let $\boldsymbol{x}(u,v)$ be as in Definition 1. Verify that $d\boldsymbol{x}_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is injective if and only if
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}{\partial u} \wedge \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}{\partial v} \neq \boldsymbol{0}.$$

Are you able to write the jacobian matrix associated to $\boldsymbol{x}$?

it is
$$J(u, v) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix} $$
right?

So how is the rank of that matrix related to injectivity of the linear map?
